# How to get canvas data and covert it using php

Tags: php, canvas

I need to fetch canvas data and decode it using PHP, my code is below:

```
<canvas id="canvas" name="canvas" class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:9px;"></canvas>
<?php
  $dataURL=$_POST['canvas'];
?>
```

Here I need to convert it into `toDataURL()` and save it into server. Is it possible without AJAX call?

Please help me.

Comment: So you want to save the canvas as image on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your canvas as image to server you have to use AJAX, you can't do it only in PHP:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "canvas_save.php",
  data: { 
     imageToSave: url
  },
  success: function(response){

  }
});
```

And in your php `canvas_save.php` script you will then have:

```
$dataURL = $_POST['imageToSave'];
$decoded_image = base64_decode($dataURL);
file_put_contents('full_path_including_file_name_and_extension', $decoded_image);
```